# Disk/drive numbers in Windows installation wizard

Tags: windows, windows-10, partitioning

When you run the Windows 10 installation wizard from a USB flash disk Windows will list all the available drives. These drives are numbered. But how are they numbered?

Before I started the installation I used diskpart to check which drive was the C: drive. Diskpart said the C: drive was disk 2. However in the Windows installation this drive is now "Drive 6".

So I have two questions. Why is the disk/drive number changed? and how can I check this beforehand? I mean obviously either diskpart or the wizard gives me the wrong disk/drive number.

[image]

Comment: The order depends on what stage Windows is in, [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/937251/disk-drive-numbers-may-not-correspond-to-the-sata-channel-numbers-when), goes into some detail on the process but doesn’t provide a full explanation.

Comment: Thanks. Seems like the solution is just to check the details of the drive. But that is not a good option if your drives are the exact same model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Before I started the installation I used diskpart to check which drive was the C: drive. Diskpart said the C: drive was disk 2. However in the Windows installation this drive is now "Drive 6".

That’s simple because your trying to compare a list of disks being enumerated by Windows to a list of disks enumerated by BIOS/UEFI.

> The BIOS may or may not enumerate disks in a specific order. There is no direct relationship between the BIOS order, and the order in which Windows numbers the disks.

After Windows takes control the following applies.

> During startup, Windows switches from using the BIOS INT13 support to native Windows drivers to access disks. Windows waits for several seconds for the system disk to enumerate through Plug and Play. When there is a match within the time-out period, normal startup will proceed.
>
> The disk numbers that are assigned by Windows after it switches to native Windows storage controller drivers during startup are dependent solely on the order in which the disks are enumerated and processed by Plug and Play. Windows will enumerate available fixed disks, followed by removable disks, assuming that the correct native Windows drivers are already present and installed on the system.
>
> how can I check this beforehand?

You can check your firmware settings to determine the order as the WinPE (Windows Pre-Installation Environment) disk enumeration would be based on the order provided by BIOS/UEFI not the Windows startup method at the disk selection stage of the installation procedure.

Source: [Here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/937251/disk-drive-numbers-may-not-correspond-to-the-sata-channel-numbers-when)